# Replace image after collision using 'if' statement

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on an html5 game based on [this](http://blog.sklambert.com/html5-game-tutorial-module-pattern/) tutorial. I'm trying to modify this 'if' statement:

```
    if (player.minDist(tokens[i]) <= player.width - platformWidth/2) {
    gameOver();
    }
```

So that instead of gameOver() running, the image is replaced with another. I've been working with:

```
ctx.drawImage(assetLoader.imgs.tokens2, 400, 240);
```

Which draws the new image to the canvas, but it doesn't replace the original or appear in the same place as the original. All images are generated with a push array and are all part of an asset loader.
I've searched in vain for 'hide()' and 'show()' examples, but can only find ones related to 'onClick' events and html elements, and can't figure out if they would be the right way to swap these images over.
Thanks for looking, hope you can help!